# How to parse 2 entities as JSON for Controller (which have 2x@RequestBody parameters)

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm wondering is it possible to parse 2 entities as one JSON for my Controller which do have 2x@RequestBody(for each entity),first i want to check if that is possible, because i would like to have one controller with 3x@RequestBody(3 entities).

Controller looks like this :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity> addCoordinator(@RequestBody KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity koordynatorzyPraktykEntity, @RequestBody OsobyEntity osobyEntity) {
        KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity addCoordinator = ikoordynatorzyPraktykService.addCoordinator(koordynatorzyPraktykEntity);
        OsobyEntity addPerson = ikoordynatorzyPraktykService.addPerson(osobyEntity, koordynatorzyPraktykEntity);
        if (addCoordinator !=null && addPerson !=null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity>(addCoordinator, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
@Override
    public OsobyEntity addPerson(OsobyEntity osobyEntity, KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity koordynatorzyPraktykEntity) {
        OsobyEntity newPerson = iosobyDAO.addPerson(osobyEntity);
        newPerson.setKoordynator(koordynatorzyPraktykEntity);
        int idOsoby = newPerson.getIdOsoby();
        koordynatorzyPraktykEntity.setIdOsoby(idOsoby);
        koordynatorzyPraktykEntity.setKoordynatorByIdOsoby(newPerson);
        return newPerson;
    }
```

Osoby(person)Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "osoby", schema = "public", catalog = "praktykidb")
public class OsobyEntity {
    private int idOsoby;
    /*
    some stuff
    */

    private KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity koordynator;

@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_osoby")
    public int getIdOsoby() {
        return idOsoby;
    }

    public void setIdOsoby(int idOsoby) {
        this.idOsoby = idOsoby;
    }
/*
some stuff
*/
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "koordynatorByIdOsoby", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity getKoordynator() {
        return koordynator;
    }

    public void setKoordynator(KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity koordynator) {
        this.koordynator = koordynator;
    }
```

and Koordynatorzy(Coordinators)Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "koordynatorzy_praktyk", schema = "public", catalog = "praktykidb")
public class KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity {
    private int idKoordynatoraPraktyk;
    private int idOsoby;
    private String doTestow;

    private OsobyEntity koordynatorByIdOsoby;
    private Collection<KoordynatorzyKierunkowiEntity> koordynatorzyByIdKierunku;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_koordynatora_praktyk")
    public int getIdKoordynatoraPraktyk() {
        return idKoordynatoraPraktyk;
    }

    public void setIdKoordynatoraPraktyk(int idKoordynatoraPraktyk) {
        this.idKoordynatoraPraktyk = idKoordynatoraPraktyk;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id_osoby")
    public int getIdOsoby() {
        return idOsoby;
    }

    public void setIdOsoby(int idOsoby) {
        this.idOsoby = idOsoby;
   /*
   some stuff
   */
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_osoby", referencedColumnName = "id_osoby", insertable = false , updatable = false)
    public OsobyEntity getKoordynatorByIdOsoby() {
        return koordynatorByIdOsoby;
    }

    public void setKoordynatorByIdOsoby(OsobyEntity koordynatorByIdOsoby) {
        this.koordynatorByIdOsoby = koordynatorByIdOsoby;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "koordynatorzyByIdKierunku", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public Collection<KoordynatorzyKierunkowiEntity> getKoordynatorzyByIdKierunku() {
        return koordynatorzyByIdKierunku;
    }

    public void setKoordynatorzyByIdKierunku(Collection<KoordynatorzyKierunkowiEntity> koordynatorzyByIdKierunku) {
        this.koordynatorzyByIdKierunku = koordynatorzyByIdKierunku;
    }
```

I know i can easilly make Person in PersonEntity and attach coordinator to this {PersonID} with @RequestMapping (value = "/{PersonID}/coordinator, method = POST (parse CoordinatorEntity as JSON and set relations for each entity), but i would like to test if something simillar (with 2xrequestBody) can work because in near future (tomorrow maybe...) i'm going to make new stuff for existing relation which looks now like this now.

```
[StudentEntity]                 [AddressEntity]
idOfStudent (PK)       /--------idOfAddress (PK)
idOfAddress (FK)<-----/
idOfPerson  (FK)<-----\         [PersonEntity]
                       \--------idOfPerson (PK)
```

With 2 entity it's not a problem, but with 3 i don't know what to do because when i make Student it assigns ID of Address and Person as 0, then when i want to add for example Address i want to search (em.find) student with his id, but he is also looking for rows in Address and Person Entity with idOfAddress = 0 and idOfPerson = 0. Maybe there is a way to make these IDs null when i persist Student into entity? Some other ideas maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong way, because the request body can be consumed only once, all subsequent attempts to process the body again will cause an IOException saying stream closed.

What you should do instead is [build and register a custom argument resolver](http://geekabyte.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-inject-objects-into-spring-mvc.html) for your types *OsobyEntity* and *KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity* and achieve the same effect.

Comment: I've made a helper class with OsobyEntity and KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity and now got problems with persisiting, I've just made a new question about this - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077299/spring-detached-entity-passed-to-persist