# Spring : detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting this errors when trying to create relation between 2 entities, this time i'm doing this in different way - passing JSON with 2 object into helper class and then getting those object and persisting them, one by one and setting the relation. When i remove setters of relation :

1. newPerson.setKoordynator(koordynatorzyPraktykEntity);

2.koordynatorzyPraktykEntity.setKoordynatorByIdOsoby(newPerson);

then it is persisting both entities without a problem, with setters only first one (KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity) is persisted (idKoordynatora = 1, idOsoby =0, test = test )

Here is the important part of error from POSTMAN ( full log http://pastebin.com/SRmnPMBH )

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: praktyki.core.entities.KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: praktyki.core.entities.KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

KoordynatorzyEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "koordynatorzy_praktyk", schema = "public", catalog = "praktykidb")
public class KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity {
    private int idKoordynatoraPraktyk;
    private int idOsoby;
    private String doTestow;

    private OsobyEntity koordynatorByIdOsoby;
    private Collection<KoordynatorzyKierunkowiEntity> koordynatorzyByIdKierunku;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_koordynatora_praktyk")
    public int getIdKoordynatoraPraktyk() {
        return idKoordynatoraPraktyk;
    }

    public void setIdKoordynatoraPraktyk(int idKoordynatoraPraktyk) {
        this.idKoordynatoraPraktyk = idKoordynatoraPraktyk;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id_osoby")
    public int getIdOsoby() {
        return idOsoby;
    }

    public void setIdOsoby(int idOsoby) {
        this.idOsoby = idOsoby;
    }

    /*
    STUFF
    */

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_osoby", referencedColumnName = "id_osoby", insertable = false , updatable = false)
    public OsobyEntity getKoordynatorByIdOsoby() {
        return koordynatorByIdOsoby;
    }

    public void setKoordynatorByIdOsoby(OsobyEntity koordynatorByIdOsoby) {
        this.koordynatorByIdOsoby = koordynatorByIdOsoby;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "koordynatorzyByIdKierunku", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public Collection<KoordynatorzyKierunkowiEntity> getKoordynatorzyByIdKierunku() {
        return koordynatorzyByIdKierunku;
    }

    public void setKoordynatorzyByIdKierunku(Collection<KoordynatorzyKierunkowiEntity> koordynatorzyByIdKierunku) {
        this.koordynatorzyByIdKierunku = koordynatorzyByIdKierunku;
    }
```

OsobyEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "osoby", schema = "public", catalog = "praktykidb")
public class OsobyEntity {
    private int idOsoby;
    private String tytulZawodowy;
    private String imie;
    private String nazwisko;
    private String email;
    private String telefonKomorkowy;
    private String telefonStacjonarny;

    private KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity koordynator;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_osoby")
    public int getIdOsoby() {
        return idOsoby;
    }

    public void setIdOsoby(int idOsoby) {
        this.idOsoby = idOsoby;
    }

    /*
     STUFF
    */


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "koordynatorByIdOsoby", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity getKoordynator() {
        return koordynator;
    }

    public void setKoordynator(KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity koordynator) {
        this.koordynator = koordynator;
    }
```

KoordynatorzyPraktykService :

```
public class KoordynatorzyPraktykService implements iKoordynatorzyPraktykService {

    @Autowired
    private iKoordynatorzyPraktykDAO ikoordynatorzyPraktykDAO;

    @Autowired
    private iOsobyDAO iosobyDAO;

    @Override
    public KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity addCoordinator(KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity koordynatorzyPraktykEntity) {
        return ikoordynatorzyPraktykDAO.addCoordinator(koordynatorzyPraktykEntity);
    }

    /*
    STUFF
    */

    @Override
    public OsobyEntity addPerson(OsobyEntity osobyEntity, KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity koordynatorzyPraktykEntity) {
        OsobyEntity newPerson = iosobyDAO.addPerson(osobyEntity);
        newPerson.setKoordynator(koordynatorzyPraktykEntity);
        System.out.println(koordynatorzyPraktykEntity.toString()); //shows idKoordynatora: 1 idOsoby: 0 test: test
        System.out.println(newPerson.toString()); //shows idOsoby: 32768 imie: Tomasz nazwisko: Potempa
        int idOsoby = newPerson.getIdOsoby();
        koordynatorzyPraktykEntity.setIdOsoby(idOsoby);
        System.out.println(koordynatorzyPraktykEntity.toString()); //shows idKoordynatora: 1 idOsoby: 32768 test: test
        koordynatorzyPraktykEntity.setKoordynatorByIdOsoby(newPerson);
        return newPerson;
    }
```

**Both DAOs have em.persist(entity)**

and POST of KoordynatorzyPraktykController:

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity> addCoordinator(@RequestBody Koordynator newCoordinator) {
        KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity addCoordinator = ikoordynatorzyPraktykService.addCoordinator(newCoordinator.getKoordynator());
        OsobyEntity addPerson = ikoordynatorzyPraktykService.addPerson(newCoordinator.getOsoba(), addCoordinator);
        if (addCoordinator !=null && addPerson !=null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity>(addCoordinator, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

Helper Class Koordynator:

```
public class Koordynator {

    private KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity koordynator;

    private OsobyEntity osoba;

    public KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity getKoordynator() {
        return koordynator;
    }

    public void setKoordynator(KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity koordynator) {
        this.koordynator = koordynator;
    }

    public OsobyEntity getOsoba() {
        return osoba;
    }

    public void setOsoba(OsobyEntity osoba) {
        this.osoba = osoba;
    }
}
```

and this is parsed JSON into controller through POSTMAN

```
{
    "koordynator":
    {
        "doTestow" : "test"
    },
    "osoba":
    {
    "tytulZawodowy" : "inzynier",
    "imie" : "Tomasz",
    "nazwisko" : "Potempa",
    "email" : "tp@tp.pl",
    "telefonKomorkowy" : "124675484",
    "telefonStacjonarny" : "654786484"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only way I got it work

Class A:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private List<B> b;
```

Class B:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "aId", referencedColumnName = "id")
private A a;

private String test;
```

Service:

```
A a = new A();

//Create without children
aFacade.create(a);

//items
List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();
B b = new B();
b.setTest("Hello");
b.setA(a);
list.add(b);

//merge
a.setB(list);
aFacade.edit(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

you hit the exception below simply because the entity isn't in the Entity Manager's session at the moment you are trying to persist it. That's due to laziness of your association.

"detached entity passed to persist: praktyki.core.entities.KoordynatorzyPraktykEntity;"

Try calling em.merge() to attach it to the session.

Comment: Tried adding to last line of Controller ikoordynatorzyPraktykDAO.merge(koordynatorzyPraktykEntity); and now the error is "Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find praktyki.core.entities.OsobyEntity with id 0" that means with this merge he wants to get information through relation but still it doesn't persist second entity (osoby). I'll try changing int idOsoby to Integer and setting it null, that could solve all problems.

Comment: yep, did it with idOsoby = null, first i persist Coordinator with setting his idOsoby to null, then persisting person on top of his idOfCoordinator  through REST "{idOfCoordinator}/person" and setting relation on both sides. Thanks for help.